# Why should I call Dispose on DataContainer or DataContext while it seems it doesn't differ?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, memory, disposable, data-containers

I create a simple test program to find out the memory and speed difference between calling Dispose vs not calling it for DataContainer object.

Here my test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        // I change the following call with Method1 and run it again
        var res = Method2();
        int count = res.Count;
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Mem: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64.ToString("N"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IList Method1()
{
    using (var db = new Model.SampleEntities())
    {
        var result = db.People.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("a")).Take(1);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}

private static IList Method2()
{
    var db = new Model.SampleEntities();
    var result = db.People.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("a")).Take(1);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

The results are the same for both methods.
The result on my PC was about 27.22 seconds and about 37.7 MB of private memory size.

Now why should I call Dispose for DataContainers while it doesn't differ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Id imagine Model.SampleEntities returns an IDisposable for a good reason - perhas properly cleaning up managed and/or unmanaged resources etc

Comment: I know but what are those resources? and why disposing them don't affect the performance?